# AnyLogic Supply Chain Driver Availability/Schedule

Tags: anylogic

I created a supply chain model with 16drivers and 10 trucks. I am currently trying to add the following constraints on the driver's availability but not able to.

1. Driver's should randomly start work on different days. Presently, because there are many orders in a day, the model seizes every driver to deliver an order every day. However, this is not the reality, drivers start work on different days of the work.
2. I want the drivers to work only for 5days and take 2 consecutive days off. For example, Driver A starts work on Tuesday and work till Saturday and take Sunday and Monday off while Driver B start work on Thursday and work till Monday and take Tuesday and Wednesday off. For each driver, this schedule should remain the same.
3. The company's driver schedule is not predetermined. The goal is to be able to use the model output to create optimal drivers schedule.

I tried using schedule element but it seems the schedule I described has to be created dynamically and I am not familiar with how to do that. Some help I have gotten suggested creating a dynamic event at the model start with 24 hours timeout. This event will set a new capacity value for the resource pool. After that, if the new capacity value is less than the total number of drivers, this event will be restarted with the same time out. However, this didn't work as expected.

Comment: Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. You actually ask *several* questions at once. Please split these into several, separate questions. This helps you and others in the future with similar problems. Some more tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this article focused on AnyLogic: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow. Welcome again, happy to help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.